# How to use javascript polyfills with dart2js

Tags: javascript, dart, polyfills, dart2js

I want to use [indexedDB](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) polyfill with Dart code compiled to Javascript. When i just added required script, dart2js code does not recognize `window.indexedDB` property as IDBFactory instance and produce `UnknownJavaScriptObject` interceptor.

I tried to force constructor.name on elements of polyfill, started with `indexedDB`:

```
    var shimIndexedDB = {
        /**
         * Force correct constructor name.
         */
        constructor: function IDBFactory(){},

        /**
         * The IndexedDB Method to create a new database and return the DB
         * @param {Object} name
         * @param {Object} version
         */
        open: function(name, version){
```

It was step forward, interceptor was correct. Unfortunately, when i added analogous construction to IDBOpenDBRequest, its object got IDBFactory interceptor as well.

How to correctly connect object and interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the [lawndart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lawndart) library instead?

It provides a common API above local storage, indexed db, and websql.

From the docs:

> You can use this library to help deal with the wide array of
>   client-side storage options. You should be able to write your code
>   against the Lawndart interface and have it work across browsers that
>   support at least one of the following: local storage, indexed db, and
>   websql.

To get the indexeddb javascript polyfill to work you would need to call its API via [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) interop. This is likely to be a lot more complicated than using a library like lawndart. Here is an [article](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) about using dart:js interop.

Comment: Lawndart seems to be good solution, i will consider integrate that into my project. Still, im looking for way to reuse javascript shims for transparent fallback with any web feature (which may not have dart library alternative).

Comment: Yeah - the problem is hooking the shim up to the Dart apis. To do this for this indexeddb shim you'd probably need to change the source of dart:html within the Dart project itself. The other option would be to copy the dart:html indexeddb interfaces, and then re-implement them using js interop.

Comment: I noticed something new in dart:js today. See [JSObject.fromBrowserObject()](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js/JsObject.html#fromBrowserObject). This should help making polyfills.